# plots in R with dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, static

I need to load the dataframe `teacher` from library "openintro".

Then, I need to provide descriptive statistics, i.e. an appropriate numerical description for the variables `degree`, `fte`, `years`, `retirement` with some graphs.

What I understand from the task is that I need to check the base salary with every variable. so. I started to find an average salary for BA degrees and then for MA.

```
library("openintro")
dat<-openintro::teacher

infoBA<-dat[dat$degree=="BA", ]
meaninfoBA<-mean(infoBA$base)
meaninfoBA

infoMA<-dat[dat$degree=="MA", ]
meaninfoMA<-mean(infoMA$base)
meaninfoMA
```

But when I do it on a plot I do not succeed. It's like there is a mistake.

Can someone help please?

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot?

Comment: For example, show the average salaries of those with a BA degree and those with an MA degree, Average salaries by percentage of position, by years of seniority...

Comment: For what i saw, `retirement` and `fica` are always fixed fractions of `base`, so there isn't much to be informed about those. Also, what is `fte`? should it be treated as a continuous variable or a discrete one?

Comment: fte is - Full-time enrollment status: full-time 1 or part-time 0.5.

Comment: Then I'd recommend doing a boxplot also. If you want a specific representation let me know

Comment: for example, I try to plot the Years of experience versus salaries with "hist" function. but it doesn't work well.

Comment: `hist(a)` will return a histogram of `a`, which is a graph that counts how many (y-axis) obs of `a` have a specific value (x-axis), so `hist` only takes one variable. What you could do is a histogram of `base` if `years==3`: hist(dat$base[dat$years==3])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways to present what you want, here are some examples:

Make a boxplot of base ~ degree:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(degree, base)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Make a scatter plot of base ~ years and draw a linear regression line on it:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(years, base)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image]

I'll think of more options and add it here.